# Having issues getting this list from an XML document

Tags: c#, xml

I have a xml document I need to serialize into a C# list.

```
<inventory>
<products>
    <product name="table" price="29.99" qty="4" />
    <product name="chair" price="9.99" qty="7" />
    <product name="couch" price="50" qty="2" />
    <product name="pillow" price="5" qty="1" />
    <product name="bed" price="225.00" qty="1" />
    <product name="bench" price="29.99" qty="3" />
    <product name="stool" price="19.99" qty="5" />
</products>
```

I've tried:

```
[XmlRoot("inventory")]
public class Inventory
{
    [XmlArray("products")]
    [XmlArrayItem("product")]
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("price")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("qty")]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Product));
                products.Add((Product) serializer.Deserialize(reader));
            }
```

Which gives me an InvalidOperationException:  was not expected.

Any help in this would be great.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pranayamr/generate-class-from-json-xml-in-visual-studio/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There two things wrong here:

- you are trying to deserialise a single `Product`, but your XML is an inventory containing multiple products. This is what is causing your exception. You want to deserialise `Inventory`
- `name`, `price` and `qty` are XML *attributes*, not *elements*

So amend your `Product` class:

```cs
public class Product
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("price")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("qty")]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

And use the correct serialiser / cast:

```cs
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Inventory));
var inventory = (Inventory)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/10hMzz) for a working demo.